# MySQL and Django Foreign Key to User model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I made this model with owner foreign key to the User model from django.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Publicacion(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    contenido = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    fechahora = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['fechahora']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Publicaciones'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.titulo, self.contenido)
```

But when I do the migrate I got this error: "django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1072, 'Key column 'owner_id' doesn't exist in table").

What else should I do?

INSTALLED APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'usuarios',
'publicaciones',
)
```

Comment: Try to flush the DB, post the content of ’ sqlmigrate' here maybe.

Comment: DId you call `makemigrations` first?

Comment: Yeah, and I got no errors.

Comment: Is `django.contrib.auth` in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes, I  updated the post with the installed apps.

Comment: The thing is that see the model  "localhost:8000/admin/publicaciones/publicacion/add" and I can see the "owner"(FK) values but when I try to save I got this "Exception Value:  (1054, "Unknown column 'owner_id' in 'field list'")"

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a column to store the foreign key in your mysql database

The field in your model must be something like:

```
 owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

And the column in your database table must be:

```
owner_id      INT(11)
```

I don't know why, but django add the "_id" to the database column name.

Also, if you don't want the database column name with the suffix "_id", you can add this in the model field:

```
db_column='owner'
```

So it must be:

```
 owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',db_column='owner')
```

But remember to create that column in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with Foreign key and User .I used OneToOneField and it worked.